# How to remotely measure the visual rendering performance of an HTML5 game?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, css-animations, telemetry

I have a simple HTML5 game that uses JavaScript and CSS animations. Even though it's visually simple, performance has been a challenge because there are ads on the page that sometimes impact it negatively or even crash the renderer.

I'm looking for ways to measure performance metrics (FPS, crashes, stutter, jitter, lag) as experienced by the end-users and send them back as anonymous telemetry. What's the best way to achieve this without setting up a physical device farm? Are there specific JavaScript APIs or tools recommended for this?

#### Current setup & challenges:

- The game is browser-based with JavaScript and CSS animations.
- I don't have control over the ads that are shown, their visual complexity, or their ability to delay or interrupt core game animations.
- There are multiple ads on the page.
- I've observed crashes, especially on iOS Safari, which I suspect might be related to the ads.
- I have not found a way to tell the renderer to prioritize my page's rendering performance ahead of the ads'.